# Learning a target feature from data

Tags: definition, feature-engineering

I have a dataset of customers (infos about them, as well as their buying behavior) to whom ads are sent regularly. How can I design a target feature that will result in a good model that predicts when customers are "responding to ads"?

Unfortunately, "responding to ads" to ads is not a precise definition. I could imagine, for example, measure for each customer how often in the past, say, `4` month he was sent an ad and how often after being sent an ad he actually bought things from it? If the threshold for a customer is bigger than, say `60%`, I could define the feature `reacts_to_ads` to be `1`, otherwise `0`.

But this seems like a really bad way to define when customers are reacting to ads, since it seems kind of arbitrary (why `4` months? Why the `60%` threshold?) and contains an awful lot of hand-designed information.

I'd rather "learn the feature from the data", but I'm not sure what the best way would be to go about that.
I could generated a collection of different features, one for each of the thresholds `45%, 50%, 55% ..., 75%` and for varying distances of looking into the past (`2` month, `2.5` month,... `6` month) and the train the same type of model for each of them and compare my test data set accuracy. But would that really be a good idea?

*How would you best go about designing such a feature?*

**EDIT** Since there were some questions regarding what kind of answer I was looking for, please see my four comments below Tim's answer, which should hopefully further disambiguate my question.

Comment: Not a complete answer but I would collect all the data and use representation learning or interpretable machine learning model to find the most predictive feature

Comment: @RahulDeora Could you please elaborate on how that should be carried out?

Comment: Check my repo: https://github.com/bluesky314/Representation-Learning-Porto-Seguro-s-Safe-Driver-Prediction to get the idea. There are two architectures. Usually people use the second and pass the intermediate feats to a ML model

Comment: I think that at least part of this, perhaps all of it, could be addressed by understanding what matters to your organization. How much "response to ads" is required for an advertising campaign to be successful? If advertising brings in a 50% return, is that successful? Then use your data to back into that number: how can you adjust "duration" and "reacts to ad percentage" to hit that 50% target among your users? Basically, there's no context-free answer to this question because different organizations have different goals.

Comment: @Sycorax I'm happy with a context-dependent answer, as long as it spells out the different assumptions it's based on (so that I might adapt these for my own purposes). So assume 50% is correct in what you mentioned.

Comment: But we don't know your context. I just made up that narrative out of whole cloth. We could rephrase your question as "What does my organization care about when it comes to advertising effectiveness?" without losing any details.

Comment: @Sycorax Making that stuff up is ok. I'm more interesting in the methods how you would approach such a problem - and less in the specific, technical details. Once I understand the methods, I can then adapt them to my own needs.

Comment: I'd find out what my company cares about and then design a method to measure that.

Comment: @Sycorax Finding out what a company ones means coaxing decision makers who have a totally flawed understanding of stats into making a stats-based decision. That's bound to go wrong. One has to do something and present it to them - and then either they'll nod it off, or ground it, but at least things are moving forward.

Comment: Welcome to the world of consulting. Yes, it's a hard job.

Comment: @Sycorax Ok :D But coming back to my question - the point that I was interested was basically whether it is possible, by using some statistical procedure, to identify among the myriad of ways one can defined that feature (which are dependent on company policy and other things) a set of features that have some certain *statistical* properties that would make them more suited than other ones for the task at hand.

Comment: I agree w/ @Sycorax, this doesn't seem like an on-topic (or even really answerable) question for this site. In addition, it seems too broad.

Comment: @gung I'd VTC but can't because of the bounty. :-\

Comment: @Sycorax, same here. Note that a person answered (w/ an upvote) on expectation that the bounty is achievable.

Comment: @gung Maybe my expectations about machine learning approaches were too high, but isn't the situation fairly common in ML where you have a set of possible target features and you want to know which one has the best statistical properties?

Comment: @Sycorax Here's one concrete example: For each threshold, as describe in my questions, one could generate a target feature, train the same model to evaluate that target feature and then evaluate via cross-validation which of the target features has lowest error etc. (But I'm sure there must be other ways) This is a stats question! Once I have the optimal feature, I can then look at the context, whether it satisfies the companies constraints (which is a non-stats questions of course, and that does not need to be answered here)

Comment: The CV procedure doesn't tell you if the target you're using is important to the firm in any way. It's really easy to predict a constant target, so if you just make a constant your target for every observation, then you'll achieve perfect CV performance -- even though that target is completely meaningless. But why do the CV procedure at all? There's no reason to do all of that work first when you have no idea what your organization cares about. In your comment, you've already decided that you'll have to ask them anyway -- that's step 1 in every statistical project: "what problem am I solving?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the example given in your question, I believe you are looking for a way to divide your population into two independent groups, specifically emphasizing responsiveness to ads.

Since you know their "buying behavior" you can use that to create an initial, estimated threshold, for example by using the median of buying frequency to classify them into two groups: above and below that median buying frequency.

Then, I would perform a regularization method like [Elastic Net](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_net_regularization) in order to simplify your multiple-dimension features to leave behind only the most important features. However, you should be lenient on this first regularization step by using a lower lambda value since your initial threshold was estimated and rather arbitrary.

Again, since your initial threshold was so arbitrary, I would then consider using [principal component analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) for further dimensionality reduction -- the difference in this method being that there is no "target" feature (i.e. buying frequency), rather PCA simply looks for a set of linearly uncorrelated variables within the whole feature set.

Lastly, I would use either [support vector machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support-vector_machine) or [random forest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_forest) and look at their top layers, which should tell you which features to look at and where to divide those features (i.e. "threshold") in order to

> define the feature `reacts_to_ads` to be 1, otherwise 0.

Again, like many of the comments to your question, there is a lot of tuning to be done within these procedures based on your goal / use / purpose for this analysis.

While some may think that Elastic Net and PCA are unnecessary, I would argue that they help you clean out the variables that do not impact your target and make your final SVM / Random Forest Trees more interpret-able.

Comment: Thanks for the interesting things you pointed out (I didn't knew about elastic net). It will take a bit of time for me to follow them up and I'll get back if there are any questions.

Comment: To clarify: By your original question, were you looking for a procedural explanation like mine, or a general theoretical explanation like @Tim's?

Comment: I will be deleting my post if I keep receiving downvotes :(

Comment: I upvoted your answer as soon as I read it. Someone else seems to have downvoted it, but it the meantime it seems to have attracted more upvotes again. Your approach definitely goes into the right direction; I'm looking for concrete suggestions that I can go through and implement (though I'm not yet sure whether I can actually make Elastic net work just by reading its Wikipedia entry, since I have never used it and it seems pretty nontrivial). But please read also my long comment in Tim's answer, where I clarify some points in my questions that perhaps were ambiguous.

Comment: I saw you haven't been active for a few days. I was hoping you could give me some more insight into Elastic net. It is a close call to whom I'll award the bounty (I would split it if possible), since both your answer and Tim (in the comments more) had contributions that were helpful

Comment: In the end, I chose to distribute rep points by giving the award to Tim, but accepting your answer. This way you both the rep. Hopefully this approach is acceptable.

Comment: @RoyceYang "While some may think that Elastic Net and PCA are unnecessary, I would argue that they help you clean out the variables that do not impact your target". This is not entirely true. PCA is a dimensionality reduction technique that does not take into account your target variable. It just reduces the number of variables based on how much variance they explain.

Comment: @Brandon You're absolutely right. It would be more accurate to say Elastic Net helps you clean out those variables, and PCA simply reduces redundant correlation.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I design a target feature that will result in a good model
>   that predicts when customers are "responding to ads"?

So I guess, that someone in your job asked you to predict *"Which customers will respond to ads?"*, but they didn't define what they mean by *"responding to ads"*. Now, you are trying to come up with your own definition "learned from the data", so to predict the learned label instead. This is not the way to go.

First, notice that if you had an algorithm that *given the data would predict that customers responds to ads* **you would already solve your problem**, no need to use the result as a target label for other algorithm, since you would already be able to predict who responds to ads! So making the labels given the data, and then predicting those labels using the data is circular.

What you should do instead, is you should come up with a definition of *something measurable to predict*. Instead of predicting that someone "responds to ads", maybe predict something like "visiting website in 24h since receiving the advertisement e-mail", or "buying product during 30 days after seeing the advertisement", etc.

Moreover, this doesn't need to be binary. You could predict things like probability of buying the product as a function of time after seeing the advertisement (check [survival analysis models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survival_analysis)), or number of bought items as a function of the number of advertisements seen (this is a linear, Poisson, or logistic regression, depending on details of the problem!).

Finally, *if* you had a way to manually (and reasonably!) label some of the customers as "responding to ads", you could use [semi-supervised learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-supervised_learning) algorithm to learn the missing labels. On another hand, if you could come up with some heuristics that approximately help in labeling such customers, you could use [Snorkel](https://www.snorkel.org/) software to help you with learning the labels based on the provided rules and the data. Notice however the meaningfulness and quality of the labels, will impact how meaningful are your results.

Comment: There is a bit of a misunderstanding going on here. Let me try to clarify the two points of issue, to hopefully make my question clearer. 1) "Should come up with a definition of something measurable to predict" This is precisely what I tried in my second paragraph, where instead of predicting "responds to ads" I chose to predict the binary feature "more than 60% proportion of products bought from ads in the last 4 month".

Comment: 2) "If you had an algorithm that given the data would predict that customers responds to ads you would already solve your problem." What I want is not to use *all* the data to derive the target feature, but only *part* of it. In my approach I use very little of the data to define my target feature. [...]

Comment: [...] One way how I could find a good target feature, which I suggested in my question, was to consider all kinds of ways I could meaningfully make "response to ads" measurable. But then I would need to compare somehow -and this is precisely what my question was about!- these different possibilites. But I don't know how.

Comment: (Maybe you could make the suggestions from your fourth paragraph (survival analysis, regression) more explicit? That paragraph seems to be heading in the right direction, in which I'm interested in. )

Comment: @user47580 If you don't know what you want to measure, how would you judge that some of those "different possibilities" works better then other? You can't. You need to decide what you want to measure. If you would first use unsupervised learning to create labels and then use supervised learning on those labels, then you would be forcing your supervised algorithm to learn to mimic the unsupervised algorithm. Better just use unsupervised learning all the way and not pretend that you know what you are measuring.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend just to use per customer:

```
responding_to_ads = bought_things / ads_received
```

Also an important metric for comparison is:

```
response_baseline = bought_things / months_customer

ads_baseline = ads_received / months_customer
```

Remarks:

Obviously, you change your problem from classification to regression, but this should be an advantage.

You can refine this by dropping customers that are new (not enough data).

As you mentioned it is also possible to only take the last 4 month into consideration. In this case I would recommend to first filter the data concerning the last 4 months and than use the metrics defined by me.